PowerShell IISAdministration: use of "-Confirm" parameter
For our reverse proxy configuration script, I need to remove current configuration elements from a collection, then add the ones we need.
Using Clear-IISCOnfigCollection, I can do what I want; after lots of experimentation, however, I have been unable to find a way around the prompt
Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Clear-IISConfigCollection" on target "Collection".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):  

I tried using the -Confirm parameter, however, this parameter takes no argument and does not change the behaviour of the command - it still asks a question that a user of the script cannot answer.
I already tried if -Force would help, to no avail - it is not known by Clear-IISConfigCollection.
Does anyone know of a way to get this command to execute without prompting?

Can you try -Confirm:$False ?

To bypass the confirmation prompt in PowerShell for a cmdlet like Clear-IISConfigCollection, you can use the -Confirm:$false syntax. Clear-IISConfigCollection -Confirm:$false, This should execute the command without any prompts. If it still prompts, you might need to use a different approach, such as wrapping the action in a try block or adjusting other PowerShell execution policies.

Thanks for all the solutions - YES, this works: -Confirm:$False

Aside from -Confirm:$False
you can also change the $ConfirmPreference variable in your session or add it to the top of your script. Valid values are High, Medium, or Low.
$ConfirmPreference=Low

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.4#confirmpreference

Thanks, @Vern_Anderson, very meticulously explained.
You and all the other respondents just made my day!

Syntactically, you must either use a quoted string (e.g. 'Low') or reference the enum value via its type (e.g., [System.Management.Automation.ConfirmImpact]::Low). However, Low is the wrong value - you're either looking for High or None (you forgot to  mention the latter as an option).
